# Using webpack's ProvidePlugin causes Hot Module Replacement to be disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, yeoman-generator

I am using the [generator-react-webpack](https://github.com/newtriks/generator-react-webpack) and when simply trying to use [webpack's ProvidePlugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin) I get the following error when the browser launches after doing `npm start`:

> Uncaught Error: [HMR] Hot Module Replacement is
>   disabled.

Here is my cfg/base.js config file being imported into webpack.config.js file. If I remove the plugins section it works ok. What am I doing wrong?

```
'use strict';

let path = require('path');
let webpack = require('webpack');
let port = 8000;
let srcPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../src');
let publicPath = '/assets/';
let additionalPaths = [];

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            _: 'lodash'
        })
    ],
    additionalPaths: additionalPaths,
    port: port,
    debug: true,
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/../dist/assets'),
        filename: 'app.js',
        publicPath: publicPath
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './src/',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
        port: port,
        publicPath: publicPath,
        noInfo: false
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            actions: srcPath + '/actions/',
            components: srcPath + '/components/',
            sources: srcPath + '/sources/',
            stores: srcPath + '/stores/',
            styles: srcPath + '/styles/',
            config: srcPath + '/config/' + process.env.REACT_WEBPACK_ENV
        }
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            include: srcPath,
            loader: 'eslint-loader'
        }],
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.sass/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&indentedSyntax'
        }, {
            test: /\.scss/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded'
        }, {
            test: /\.less/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.styl/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: What version of `generator-react-webpack` do you use? Basically the recent versions use `Object.apply()` to merge the base configuration with the specific environment configuration (dev, test or dist). **However**, `Object.apply()` would rule out the `plugins` property in the base.js file, so that doesn't really explain a change in behavior (because the plugins defined in base.js would simply be ignored). I verified that right now with a fresh installation. If you are on the latest generator-react-webpack version, are there any other modifications that could lead to this?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar kind of issue where just adding `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({})` to the base configuration breaks the HMR. However, when I add it straight to `cfg/dev.js`, everything works

Comment: @rjo adding to dev.js works thanks